# Flask: Render jinja template with response from POST-request

Tags: python, jquery, flask, jinja2

I have an online store that uses local storage to keep track of which products are in the cart (stored like `cart = [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"4"}]`). When the user navigates to cart.html, I want to send `cart` to my backend, generate a complete list of the products, and then use the list in a `return render_template` call.

The backend recieves the `cart` just fine and can generate the list without a problem, but I can't get the list to the cart.html page (it looks like if `cart` is empty). Should the POST request not be on cart.html and instead solve it with redirects? If so, how do I do that? I'd like to avoid having a "load cart" button on cart.html if possible.

This the beginning of cart.html (I've tried setting the ajax call to async: false, but it didn't stop the page from rendering without `cart`:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendCart() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url_for('cart', _external=True) }}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
            }); 
        })
    }
    sendCart();
</script>
...
```

And here is my route:

```
@app.route('/cart', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def cart():
    cart = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in request.json:
            cart.append(get_Furniture(int(i['id'])))
        return render_template("cart.html", cart_objects = cart)
    return render_template("cart.html", cart_objects = cart)
```

### Edit: Solved

I found it easier to skip using ajax and localstorage, instead using a cookie that is easy to access in the backend: without the need for a request I can generate `cart` before rendering the page.

Comment: what is `get_Furniture` doing here?

Comment: It's the function for getting the products from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to skip using ajax and localstorage, instead using a cookie that is easy to access in the backend: without the need for a request I can generate cart before rendering the page.